# Get bean->id when in _headerModuleList.tpl (suiteCRM, SugarCRM CE)

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm trying to adjust the nav bar at the very top when inside a specific bean, but I can't figure out how to read the current module name/bean->id
(or if it's even possible).

As a workaround I thought of indicating a custom header, but in meta we can only put custom headerTPL, example

```
        $viewdefs[mod][DetailView][templateMeta][form][headerTpl] => 'custom/themes/SuiteP/tpls/headerModuleList_c.tpl',
```

But we can't indicate a custom headerMODULELIST it seems

Would appreciate your help

Comment: Did you tried $_REQUEST['module']  and $_REQUEST['record'] ?

Comment: @AshishDwivedi thank you! Strangely enough it shows module as just "home" even when in a different module and no record

Comment: @AshishDwivedi the URL parameters of the module, record etc. come after the # sign so from what I've read it's an indicator that it's set by JS

Answer (score 1):

You can USE Jquery as well with ajax enabled or even ajax disabled modules. This is beneficial for you only if you need these values at Browser Side.
Anyhow,

Try these

$("input:hidden[name='record']").val()
$("input:hidden[name='module']").val()

For going more specific you can access it by Parent Form ID

$("form#formDetailView input:hidden[name='module']").val()
$("form#formDetailView input:hidden[name='record']").val()

For Server Side you can try this thing to get URL and you can parse it accordingly

$url =  "//{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";

Answer (score 0):

In the end the only thing that worked for me is disabling the AjaxUI which loads the page partially and makes any sort of complex modification to the header navigation pretty difficult

Once disabled you can just call $_REQUEST in _headerModuleList.tpl to get all the details you need